# What is the difference between “verdad” and “cierto” when used in the form of a question?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

What is the difference between “verdad” and “cierto” when used in the form of a question? is there a difference?

> Ayer fue su cumpleaños, ¿verdad?

vs.

> Ayer fue su cumpleaños, ¿cierto?

Anecdotally, when I watch Colombian shows I seem to hear cierto fairly often whereas I tend to hear verdad more in Spanish shows. It might be a regional thing?

This is a follow up question from this thread on the [difference between ser cierto/ser verdad](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-difference-between-ser-cierto-and-ser-verdad#2707) even after reading this it wasn’t entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal? diferencia entre “verdad” y “cierto”.

A veces el idioma no se utiliza tan bien como debiera, provocando con ello fallos y confusiones.

En líneas generales y a nivel de calle ambos términos son utilizables, sin embargo ante la pregunta "Ayer fue su cumpleaños, ¿verdad?", la certeza siempre es más adecuada, "Ayer fue su cumpleaños, ¿cierto?", mejor que la verdad, ya que *la certeza* es la convicción del sujeto, que puede estar ó no en lo cierto, mientras que *la verdad* es un conocimiento objetivo y compartible entre sujetos, y por tanto, debería ser utilizada solo para una afirmación ó una pregunta en que ya se sabe la respuesta.

No obstante, lo más lógico y lo que se suele hacer es realizar la pregunta previniendo la posibilidad de que algo haya sucedido ya con certeza (subjetiva) ó verdad (absoluta), y así solemos decir;

*"Ayer fue su cumpleaños, ¿no?"*

ó simplemente

*"¿Fue ayer su cumpleaños?"*

Espero te haya ayudado. Saludos.

Diego M.

Answer (score 0):

Both, *¿verdad?* and *¿cierto?* should not be considered as elements that contribute meaning to sentence, nor as part of its grammatical structure. They are "conversational markers" that are interspersed from time to time in the speech and used for example to maintain contact between the interlocutors or to deliver the turn.

Other examples: *¿sí?, ¿no?, ¿te fijas?, ¿me sigues?, ¿claro? ¿okey?*

Don't worry about its meaning because really they do not have it, in these cases it is better to talk about a "function". And both meet exactly the same function equivalent to the English form "*you know*".

(I'm talking about *¿verdad?* and *¿cierto?* only when they are interrogative and interspersed between sentences).

Comment: They most definitely have a function as verbal markers, and can be translated as isn't it, wasn't it, doesn't it, etc. etc. etc, as emphatic markers or tags in English.